# ganglia is missing some metrics of some nodes

Tags: cluster-computing, ganglia

I use ganglia to monitor performance-related metrics of cluster nodes.

I installed gmond python modules for richer functionality.

However, some metrics from some nodes are missing (i.e. disk_*_read_bytes_per_sec)

There are a few nodes that work as expected reporting the metrics.
But some nodes are missing either **disk_*_read_bytes_per_sec*** or **disk__write_bytes_per_sec** or **both of them**.

If I restart gmond daemon some work correctly again and some work incorrectly again....

I checked /etc/ganglia/gmond.conf, /etc/ganglia/conf.d/* configurations files. All the computation nodes in the cluster have the exactly same configuration settings. How can they behave such differently? Where should I check first to resolve the problem?

Thanks